# Baire Property on Baire Spaces (Kechris' book)

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Kechris states the following result in "Classical Descriptive Set Theory", pp. $48$:

> **($\boldsymbol{8.26}$) Proposition**
>   Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose that $A\subseteq X$ has the BP (Baire Property). 
>   Then either $A$ is meager or there is a nonempty open set $U\subseteq X$ s.t. $A$ is comeager in $U$.
>
> If $X$ is a Baire space, exactly one of these alternatives holds.

Well, I'm not able to prove the last assertion. I've worked on it for some time and maybe I can't something different from what I have already tried (I think the proof is very elementary).

For the convenience  of the reader, I recall that

> $A$ has the **BP** iff there  is an open set $U\subseteq X$ s.t. the symmetric difference $A\triangle U$ is meager;
>
> $X$ is a **Baire space** If it satisfies one of the following equivalent conditions:
>   (i) every nonempty open set in $X$ is non-meager; 
>   (ii) every comeager set in $X$ is dense;
>   (iii) the intersection of countably many dense open sets on $X$ is dense.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already proved the first assertion, then the second assertion just says that a meager set $A$ can't be comeager in a nonempty open set $U$. Well, suppose $A$ is meager, $U$ is nonempty and open, and $U-A$ is meager. Then $U$, being included in the union of two meager sets $A$ and $U-A$, is meager, contrary to the assumption that $X$ is a Baire space.

Comment: I thought that it was simple, but this is a great blunder! I would like to thank you for this proof... I was in trouble at that moment :)